# Cannot send request in React App because of CORS, even with CORS enabled on my server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

This is how I configure my server

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'));
```

Now, I would imagine that since I used the `cors` package, and I have it enabled for all origins, my requests would go through in my app. Well, it didn't because every time I try to send a request to the server, it would give me a CORS error.

Interesting bypass I am using: I start my server on port `3000` (the port of CRA). If I start the server first, then start my React app, CRA would prompt me to switch to a different port. Now, I can send requests to my server without the hassle of CORS. However, how would I correctly enable CORS in my app?

Full error from browser:

```
TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/accounts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/accounts. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

UPDATE: I have

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) { 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
})
```

in my server, but for some reason, when the response is being sent, it doesn't have the headers?

Comment: Can you share the full error please ? As returned in your browser's console.

Comment: @BENARDPatrick Just edited my code to have the full error

Comment: Is your client running on localhost?

Comment: Yeah it is, but on different ports

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: I get a 200 OK on the OPTIONS request, but there are no Allow CORS headers in the response

Comment: If you have to set those headers the way you are, then something is wrong. Per the express docs https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests simply doing `app.use(cors())` (which you originally had) should work.

Comment: Look at the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html), you've to set the origin inside the cors configuration, not directly in the res header... The doc will help you.

Comment: Btw it works on my friend's machine, but not mine for some reason. On my machine, the server doesn't set the Allow CORS headers

Answer (score -1):

‍ **Try to use** this in your server:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: '*'}));
```

**Make sure**, when you call the endpoint from your React App, dont use: `localhost`, but using: `http://localhost`.

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: I don't know, why it's didn't work in yours, but before I answer your question, I try it first and it's working fine.

Comment: Strange for me too that it didn't work. Your answer worked for my friends as well, but for me, it returned a 200 OK response, but didn't return any of the `Access-Control-Allow-` headers